# Compiling for multiple sdk versions

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed SDK 16 (android 4.1), 20 (android 4.4) and 27 (android 8.1) and the code is configured with the following specs

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.android"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 25
    versionName "2.6.7"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

I want to make sure that the app is fine when installing on an android 4.1. Is that enough to modify `compileSdkVersion` to 16? Or I have to change `buildToolsVersion` accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

target and compile level should be the highest possible and you must do so as Google will happen to reject low targets in the future.

Incompatible code will be noted in the IDE as red warnings as you develop. Usually with such a warning as: "Code XX need a newer version (22) and minSdk is 16"
Those errors make your app incompatible for older for versions.

Comment: The `minSdkVersion` is 16 according to the developers. So, I want to be sure that android 4.1 is also supported.

Comment: Android level 16 is the 4.1 version, the application will be compatible only if don't use newer code as I stated above

Comment: But when I want to install on 4.1.2, the installation fails. However, on android 7 there is no problem

Comment: What message? Note that when running from AndroidStudio devices incompatibles will be noted and unavaiable to choose

Comment: The package manager says "App not install" with no more information

Comment: Try to install using the SDK with /Sdf/platform-tools adb install <path-to-apk>/filename.apk the error messages there is supossed to be better